# How to toggle my menu with right swipe on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my simple menu: I want it to be closed by default when I open on a mobile **and if I swap right to left then it should open**.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,700);
@import url(http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);
.accordion {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion .section {
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  background: #363636;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 3px solid #21CCFC;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked ~ .content {
  max-height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.accordion .section label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: table;
  background: #222;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.accordion .section label:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #363636;
}
.accordion .section label:hover {
  background: #363636;
}
.accordion .section label span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.accordion .section:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
}
.accordion .section .content {
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #666;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.left-menu {
  background: #222;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.accordion .section .content {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked ~ .content {
  padding: 15px;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li i {
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover i {
  color: #21CCFC;
}

.logo {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.logo i {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #21CCFC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pure CSS Accordion Nav</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="left-menu">
  <div class="logo"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
    <div>Pure CSS Accordion Nav</div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="section">
      <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-1" checked="checked"/>
      <label for="section-1"><span>Messages</span></label>
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i><span>Inbox</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-share"></i><span>Sent    </span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-archive"></i><span>Archive</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-2" value="toggle"/>
      <label for="section-2"> <span>Usage</span></label>
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>System</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-group"></i><span>Users    </span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i><span>Visitation</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-3" value="toggle"/>
      <label for="section-3"> <span>Scroller</span></label>
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee    </span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee    </span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee</span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee    </span></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span>Need Coffee</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-4" value="toggle"/>
      <label for="section-4"> <span>Section 4</span></label>
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I require to make a very very simple pop out menu with no button.